# Average of multiple six month periods

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to create a average that goes by six month intervals till the start of time for the database. For week I have this, I imagine the answer will be something similar.

```
SELECT AVG(q1.Entry1) as AvgPerWeek
FROM (SELECT COUNT(TestID) as Entry1, DATEPART(wk, TestDate) as Wk
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Year(TestDate), DATEPART(wk, TestDate))q1
```

A secondary choice I have is to attempt to do this through SSRS, if anyone has any thoughts on doing that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no function available invent one! I'd use CASE:

```
SELECT AVG(q1.Entry1) as AvgPerWeek
FROM (SELECT COUNT(TestID) as Entry1, Year(TestDate),
      CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, TestDate) between 1 AND 6 
       THEN 'first half' ELSE 'second half' END as term
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Year(TestDate), 
               CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, TestDate) between 1 AND 6 
                    THEN 'first half' ELSE 'second half' 
               END
     ) q1
```